# Dynamic switching of dropout in Keras/Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, dropout

I am building a reinforcement learning algorithm in Tensorflow and I would like to be able to dynamically turn dropout off and then on within one single call to `session.run()`.

*Rationale*: I need to (1) do a forward pass w/o dropout to calculate the targets; and (2) do a training step with the generated targets. If I execute these two steps in different calls to `session.run()`, everything is ok. But I would like to do it with one single call to `session.run()` (using `tf.stop_gradients(targets)`).

After trying several solutions w/o much success, I landed on a solution where I replace the *learning_phase* placeholder used by Keras with a variable (since placeholders are tensors and do not allow assignments) and use a custom layer to set that variable to True or False as desired. This solution is shown in the code below. Getting the value of either `m1` or `m2` separately (e.g., running `sess.run(m1, feed_dict={ph:np.ones((1,1))})`works as expected w/o error. However, getting the value of `m3`, or getting the values of `m1` and `m2` simultaneously, works sometimes and sometimes not (and the error message is uninformative).

Do you know what I am doing wrong or a better way to do what I want?

**EDIT:** The code shows a toy example. In reality I have a single model and I need to run two forward passes (one with dropout off and the other with dropout on) and one backward pass. And I want to do all this it w/o returning to python.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout, Dense, Input, Layer
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras import Model
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class DropoutSwitchLayer(Layer):
  def __init__(self, stateful=True, **kwargs):
    self.stateful = stateful
    self.supports_masking = True
    super(DropoutSwitchLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

  def build(self, input_shape):
    self.lph = tf.Variable(True, dtype=tf.bool, name="lph", trainable=False)
    K._GRAPH_LEARNING_PHASES[tf.get_default_graph()] = self.lph
    super(DropoutSwitchLayer, self).build(input_shape)

  def call(self, inputs, mask=None):
    data_input, training = inputs
    op = self.lph.assign(training[0], use_locking=True)
    # ugly trick here to make the layer work
    data_input = data_input + tf.multiply(tf.cast(op, dtype=tf.float32), 0.0)
    return data_input

  def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    return input_shape[0]


dropout_on = np.array([True], dtype=np.bool)
dropout_off = np.array([False], dtype=np.bool)
input_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 1))

drop = Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.bool)
input = Input(shape=(1,))
h = DropoutSwitchLayer()([input, drop])
h = Dense(1)(h)
h = Dropout(0.5)(h)
o = Dense(1)(h)
m = Model(inputs=[input, drop], outputs=o)

m1 = m([input_ph, dropout_on])
m2 = m([input_ph, dropout_off])
m3 = m([m2, dropout_on])

sess = tf.Session()
K.set_session(sess)
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

**EDIT 2:** Daniel Möller's solution below works when using a `Dropout` layer, but what if using dropout inside an `LSTM` layer?

```
input = Input(shape=(1,))
h = Dense(1)(input)
h = RepeatVector(2)(h)
h = LSTM(1, dropout=0.5, recurrent_dropout=0.5)(h)
o = Dense(1)(h)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not make a single continuous model?

```
#layers
inputs = Input(shape(1,))
dense1 = Dense(1)
dense2 = Dense(1)

#no drop pass:
h = dense1(inputs)
o = dense2(h)
#optionally:
o = Lambda(lambda x: K.stop_gradient(x))(o)

#drop pass:
h = dense1(o)
h = Dropout(.5)(h)
h = dense2(h)

modelOnlyFinalOutput = Model(inputs,h)
modelOnlyNonDrop = Model(inputs,o)
modelBothOutputs = Model(inputs, [o,h])
```

Choose one for training:

```
model.fit(x_train,y_train) #where y_train = [targets1, targets2] if using both outputs
```

Comment: That is not an option. As I explain, I need this for a reinforcement learning algorithm. The code shows a toy example replicating the problem. I edited my question to be clear on this. Sorry

Comment: I don't understand why this is not an option. It's exactly that. Two forward passes in the same model. The second with dropout. If you want you can add a `o = Lambda(lambda x: K.stop_gradient(x))(o)` to not propagate the backpass entirely.

Comment: Sorry again. It is true this could work if using a Dropout layer, as in my toy example. However, I am using dropout inside an LSTM (`LSTM(int(lstm_size, dropout=0.5, recurrent_dropout=0.5))`). In this case I think the strategy you propose cannot be used, right? Or am I wrong?

Comment: Uhmm, then it gets complicated...but you can still try to create a single model from m2 and m3. But this would need testing. I'm in a hurry right now...

Comment: It turns out Keras supports, out of the box, what I want to do. Using the _training_ argument in the _call_ to the Dropout/LSTM layer, in combination with @danielm 's approach to build the model (thanks!), does the trick. I have added an answer

Answer (score 1):

It turns out Keras supports, out of the box, what I want to do. Using the *training* argument in the *call* to the Dropout/LSTM layer, in combination with Daniel Möller's approach to build the model (thanks!), does the trick.

In the code below (just a toy example), `o1` and `o3` should be equal and different than `o2`

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout, Dense, Input, Lambda, Layer, Add, RepeatVector, LSTM
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras import Model
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

repeat = RepeatVector(2)
lstm = LSTM(1, dropout=0.5, recurrent_dropout=0.5)

#Forward pass with dropout disabled
next_state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 1), name='next_state')
h = repeat(next_state)
# Use training to disable dropout
o1 = lstm(h, training=False)
target1 = tf.stop_gradient(o1)

#Forward pass with dropout enabled
state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 1), name='state')
h = repeat(state)
o2 = lstm(h, training=True)
target2 = tf.stop_gradient(o2)

#Forward pass with dropout disabled
ph3 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 1), name='ph3')
h = repeat(ph3)
o3 = lstm(h, training=False)

loss = target1 + target2 - o3
opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1)
train = opt.minimize(loss)

sess = tf.Session()
K.set_session(sess)
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

data = np.ones((1,1))
sess.run([o1, o2, o3], feed_dict={next_state:data, state:data, ph3:data})
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this :

```
class CustomDropout(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomDropout, self).__init__()
        self.dropout1= Dropout(0.5)
        self.dropout2= Dropout(0.1)

    def call(self, inputs):
       if xxx:
           return self.dropout1(inputs)
       else:
           return self.dropout2(inputs)
```